# Legend isnt moving to the right on my doughnut chart created with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

For some reason, the legend on this doughnut chart created with chart.js is not moving to the right. Even tried adding the rule to chart creation itself instead of putting it in the variable

EDIT

With further inspection, it appears any options that are set to the legend do not appear to be working.

```
const mobileData = {
    labels: ["Desktop", "Tablet", "Phons"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Users',
        data: [2000, 550, 500],
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: [
            '#7477BF',
            '#78CF82',
            '#51B6C8'
        ]
    }]
};

const mobileOptions = {
    legend: {
        position: 'right',
        labels: {
            boxwidth: 20,
            fontStyle: 'bold'
        }
    }
}

let mobileChart = new Chart(mobileCanvas,  {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: mobileData,
    options: mobileOptions
});
```

Here's a fiddle to the project minus images.
https://jsfiddle.net/5j2ucpv6/3/

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet or fiddle? A GitHub link does not help...

Comment: sure ill edit the original article

Answer (score 1):

You are using the new V3 version of the lib instead of V2

So please read the migration guide from chart.js (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

The legend options have been moved to the plugin section like this

```
options: {
   plugins: {
      legend: {
         position: 'right'
       }
    }
 }
```